# How to Select the Entire content with Xpath selector in Scarpy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Hello I was scraping a site but then I ran into trouble because of the structure of the site,

Here is one page of the site `https://www.dehatilyrics.top/2018/09/dilli-wali-gori-ridam-tripathi-lyrics.html`

I want to get the main body of content excluding the Song Info part, As you can see there are many span tags, I can't understand how to get the entire page at once.

Here is what I tried,

`response.xpath('//*[@class="post-body entry-content"]/div[1]/span/text()').extract()`

This returned me a part of the entire content the bottom part How to get the entire content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Song Info you mean this part?

```
Song :- Dilli Wali Gori 
Singer :- Ridam Tripathi
Lyrics & Composition :- Ridam Tripathi
Music Director :- Ajay Verma "AV"
Video Director :- Shunty
Dop :- Govind Bist
Company/ Label :- Wave
```

Since that is in the first `span`, so you can exclude it using list slicing,

You can get it like this

```
entire_body = " ".join(response.xpath('//*[@class="post-body entry-content"]/div[1]/span//text()').extract()[1:])
entire_body = "".join(entire_body)
```

You can always do that to check Selectors/Xpaths

[image]

Comment: Hello Thanks for giving your time dear, But sorry to say this is also not giving the entire content it is giving the bottom half

Comment: @AbhijeetPal what do you want? the entire lyrics of songs only?

Comment: Yes sir that's what I'm looking for

Comment: everything after this line ``Patna ke pani puri lucknow ke kabab deb``

Comment: Hello Sir I am really sorry I am asking this irrelevant question but can you tell me the XPath of the next page in the homepage?

Comment: @AbhijeetPal `response.css("a.blog-pager-older-link::attr(href)").extract_first()`

Comment: Sir do you use any extension to find out the paths?

Comment: @AbhijeetPal see updated answer on how to get xpath/css

Comment: I ran your next page selector plus made some on mine which should work but it gives nothing, not even an empty dictionary what does that mean?

Comment: I am trying to get into next pages starting from here ``https://www.dehatilyrics.top/?m=1``